# Javascript object is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is the code snippet I have:

```
var records = Ext.data.Record.create([{name: 'msgId', type:'string', mapping: 'msgId'},]);
...
...
var detailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  id:'detailGrid',
  store: dataStore,
  cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns: [
      {id:'msgId',hidden: true, dataIndex: 'msgId'},  
      {header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick = "viewMessage(records)">View Message Details</a>'} 
    ]
}),
```

When it comes to `onClick = "viewMessage(records)"`, I get : `'records' is undefined.`
What is wrong here?

EDIT:The solution given works to remove the error. But when I put in a function like this:

```
function viewMessage(records){
alert(Ext.util.JSON.encode(records));
}
```

I get `{}` as alert i.e. no data.

Comment: Not sure but you may want to remove the comma at the end of line 1

Comment: Right after you create "records" alert one of its values to make sure the object was created properly and not failing silently for some reason.

Comment: Ok... there is some stuff after the comma..i edited my post

Comment: Where does this code snippet exist?  Is `records` available at the global level?

Comment: @s_hewitt:Not at global level, but `records` and `detailGrid` are  inside the same function

Comment: That is the issue then.  The template column does not bring any scope with it. Once that anchor tag is on the page, none of the ExtJs code matters, it is just a normal javascript function call - all standard scope rules apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
'<a href="#"  onClick = "viewMessage('+records+')">View Message Details</a>'
```

Comment: That will convert `results` into a string, which will not have the desired result I think.

Comment: This works to remove the error. But does not produce the desired result. Please see my EDIT

Comment: In fact, the original question was a syntax error. As pimvdb immediately noticed a cast occurs. However in the initial post, we didn't have any knowledge about viewMessage. I agree using ext events is a better way though

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explained why it's not working... your handler expects records to be a global variable, your handler is called and does not know where to get records from.

What you really should be doing is setting a listener for a 'headerclick' on your column model like

```
// EXT 4 version: wrap with Ext.onReady
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224" },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244" },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254" }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    colModel: {
        listeners: { 
            headerclick: function(container, column, e, target, options) {
                if (column.id == 'col-name') {
                    alert('Anything you want');
                }
            }
        },
        items: [
            { header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', id: 'col-name', sortable: false},
            { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
            { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
        ]},
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

You mentioned that you're using Ext 3, the headerclick is slightly different, it should be set on the grid itself, instead of in the header container (column model). Something like

```
var records = Ext.data.Record.create([{name: 'msgId', type:'string', mapping: 'msgId'},]);
...
...
var detailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  listeners: {
    headerclick: function(grid, index, e) {
       if (index == 1) {
         alert('Clicked Grid');
       }
    }
  },
  id:'detailGrid',
  store: dataStore,
  cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns: [
      {id:'msgId',hidden: true, dataIndex: 'msgId'},  
      {header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#">View Message Details</a>'} 
    ]
}),
```

Comment: Thanks. But 'View Message Details' is not clickable with this code.

Comment: By clickable, do you mean no underline? Or do you mean nothing happens when you click on it? Your comment doesn't explain much about what's not working. I tried it on my machine and I can click the header and see an alert popup.

Comment: There is no underline. And when I click the 'View Message Details' text, i cannot see alert.

Comment: The underline must be added with CSS... Are you using Ext 4 or 3?

Comment: Ext 3.3.1. This is the version

Comment: Updated the example with something that you can pop into any place with ext-all and have it work.

Comment: Thanks. 'View Message Details' is now a hyperlink, but on clicking it, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the return value of `Ext.data.Record.create` if you can provide a bit more context about what `Ext.data.Record.create` does exactly then I can help troubleshoot.

Try setting up a `console.log(records);` right after you assign the `records` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to have some way of getting the `records` in scope.

According to your comment, it sounds like you have this structure - a script file that contains:

```
function creategrid(){
    var records = Ext.data.Record.create....
    var detailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({...
    {header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick  = "viewMessage(records)">View Message Details</a>'}
    ...});
}
```

After that code is executed and the grid is rendered, you will have html similar to this on your page:

```
<tr><td class="templatecolumncssclass"><a href="#" onClick="viewMessage(records)">View Message Details</a></td></tr>
```

When you click on the anchor tag, the `viewMessage` function is called with the global variable `records` as its argument.  This will not work, since in your snippet, records is not setup as a global variable.

You need to make `records` available in the scope of the page:

```
var GridCreation = {};
GridCreation.records = {};
GridCreation.creategrid = function(){
    var records = Ext.data.Record.create....
    GridCreation.records = records;
    var detailGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({...
    {header: 'info',xtype: 'templatecolumn',tpl: '<a href="#"  onClick  = "viewMessage(GridCreation.records)">View Message Details</a>'}
    ...});
};
```

Comment: Creating a global variable to solve a problem is a nasty suggestion

Comment: The global variable is only there to illustrate the solution.  I will make that more clear, but with such a limited code snippet, it is hard to put up an example of how to apply it in the posters case.

Comment: If you don't know that you can listen for Ext events on the column headers, then yeah, I would probably add a global too :p